# Trying to understand an example of an equivlance relation that is symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, self-learning, relations, equivalence-relations

I am just tying to figure our this example but am having difficulty understand the math being used.

The example state: Let R be a relation on the set $\mathbb{Z}$ defined as (m,n)$\in$ R if and only if 5|(m + 4n). We show first that R is an equivalent relation.

Reflexive: For m $\in \mathbb{Z}$, we have m + 4m =5m, and therefore 5 divides m + 4m and (m,m) $\in$ R.  For this, I believe that because both m and n are in the relation R then |m|=|n| and so m can be substituted for n giving (m,m). Is this correct?

Symmetric: If (m,n) $\in R$, then 5|(m + 4n). Thus, 5k = m + 4n for some k $\in \mathbb Z$. We want to show that 5|(n + 4m). Hence,

(Line 1)
$$(4)5k = 20k = 4(m+4n) = 4m + 16n,$$

(Line 2)
$$n + 4m = n + 20k - 16n = 5(4k - 3n)$$

(Line 3)
$$and 5|(n + 4m).$$

In line one, it appears that both side of the equation are being multiplied by 4 but I don't understand why. Could someone explain why this is the case?

In line two, I don't understand whe n + 4m = n + 20k - 16n

I understand the rest but not these two part. Any help is welcome.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: I believe the last term in line 1 should be 16n (instead of 16), and this line is being multiplied by 4 to create the term 4m.  In line 2, 4m is being replaced by 20k-16n using line 1.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. 20k-16n is being substituted for 4m. And, we want 4m so that we can do that substitution in line 2. Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following is a cleaner approach. We are using the fact that if a number divides two numbers, then it also divides their sum and their difference. Using this, we would like to sum or subtract appropriate numbers to get from $5\mid n+4m$ to $5\mid 4n+m$.

Now, we know $5\mid n+4m$, and trivially $5\mid 5m+5n$. By the first comment $5\mid n+4m\color{red}{-5m}-\color{blue}{5n}$. This equals $-4n-m$, we so know $5\mid -4n-m$. But of course, if a number divides $-a$ it also divides $a$, so we get $5\mid 4n+m$ a we wanted.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why you are doing the equations this way. Would you mind explaining what you are doing?

Comment: @Tony I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Even cleaner: If $5\mid n+4m$, then $5\mid 4(n+4m)=4n+16m=(4n+m)+15m$.  Certainly $5\mid 15m$, whence $5\mid 4n+m$.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why you are doing the equations this way. Would you mind explaining what you are doing?